# Laravel help: After analyzing my server log - data stolen?

Tags: php, laravel

I use the framework [Laravel](https://laravel.com/).

I just analyzed my server logs and although the folder is nowhere linked or mentioned in the `robot.txt`, someone found it.

Someone went to `"hiddenfolder/public/auth/login"`

Thats ok, because he could not log in, but then he went to `"hiddenfolder/public/auth/login/search_customers"` and other urls like `"/public/get_autocomplete"` (I have a autocomplete function in that search).

Of course, these URLs do not exist, but surely he tried to get access to my data.

Now I want to know: Can someone explain what he tried out and is there a possibility that he could see any customer information?

Comment: If `search_customers` and `get_autocomplete` are encapsulated in the `authentication` group (sounds like they are/should be), then the person wouldn't have access because like you stated, they are not logged in. On your server, where are these files actually living? The only thing that should be in `public` are things like images, css, etc. Everything else should be one level lower, beneath `public`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. After your comment I searched in the whole Laravel directories for terms like `search_customers` and `get_autocomplete`. And I found them all in two files `resources\views\XXX.blade.php` and `\storage\framework\views\ue17bdwqi26uwe49dwe79qutfwqdq`